# compare operation in a pandas rolling window

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a rolling window and compare the elements in this window with the most recent one. In fact I want to subtrack the last value from all the the others. For example if we have the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [2, 3, 5, 7,],
    [8, 3, 6, 1],
    [1, 5, 9, 13],
    [7, 3, 2, 7],
    [12, 4, 1, 0]
])
```

I would like to make a rolling window of length 4, hence in this particular case, the first window will be [2, 8, 1, 7]. Now the last element (which is 7) is greater than 2 and 1 but smaller than 8, hence the output of the operation will be -1+1-1 = -1 (-1 if greater, +1 if smaller. If equal, it doesnt really matter but lets we give a +1). Similarly for the next rolling window. Now, 12 is greater than all the values in the the window, therefore the operation will return -3.

The ideal output finally will be:

```
[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
[-1,  3,    3,  1  ]
[ -3,  -1   3,  3  ]
```

I tried with `pd.rolling().apply()`, also with `df.shift` but couldnt get anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be `rolling.apply` with a custom lambda, where `g.iloc[:-1] - g.iat[-1] >= 0` compares all previous elements with the last element in the window:

```
df.rolling(window=4).apply(lambda g: np.where(g.iloc[:-1] - g.iat[-1] >= 0, 1, -1).sum())

     0    1    2    3
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3 -1.0  3.0  3.0  1.0
4 -3.0 -1.0  3.0  3.0
```

Comment: thanks so much! I was doing something like `df.rolling(4).apply(lambda x: x - x[-1])` but i was getting nonsense.. Yours is so nice. I dont get why my code doesnt work though... anyways thanx!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)'s [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html)

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

N = 4

a = df.to_numpy()

out = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

out.iloc[N-1:,:] = \
np.where(swv(a, (N-1,1))[:-1] >= a[N-1:][..., None, None],
         1, -1).sum(axis=(-1,-2))

print(out)
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2    3
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   -1    3    3    1
4   -3   -1    3    3
```